# Exporting Featureclass to Shapefile with field names changed using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, vb

I have some annotation feature classes stored in a Pgdb.I want to export them to a shape file.Some field name need too be changed in that shape file.I am using vb .net to do this.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to export annotation to .shp? You cannot have an annotation shapefile so you can only export it to a geodatabase (personal, file or SDE) or a coverage. (This is assuming you're talking about ArcGIS)

Comment: Thanks Loz    If pInFeatureClass.FeatureType = esriFeatureType.esriFTAnnotation Then
            pExportOp = New ExportOperation()
            pExportOp.ExportFeatureClass(pInDsName, Nothing, Nothing, pGeometryDef, pOutDatasetName, Nothing)
    End If                                                           Above code is working fine to export a featureclass to shapefile.But i am unable to change the field name through this code.And Yes, I am working with ArcGis.Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

As fas as i know you cannot change the field names or types on export. You have 3 options:

1. build an exporter that does this,
2. create an empty shapefile with the fields you want first and load the exported features into it using a field map. Or
3. export the feature class, then add fields and calculate the values into the new field, then delete the original field... all three are kind of a pain.

Look at this exporting example. 
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/91E3E8A0-D355-43D2-A201-0A8CEB719334.htm
you may be able to change the output field object at the IFields sourceFields = sourceFeatureClass.Fields line. 
I have not tried it so I don't know if it will validate.